# Asynchronous image frame and processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In the following code I have this method which takes the image frame from a webcam and processes the image by running object tracking and face recognition.
Because the image processing does take time to process, I was trying to have multiple processes or an async method to have these processes run pararell to each other.

1. We want to run the capture and display of the image
2. We want to process the image frame pararell.

This means that while the image is being processed we still want the the other frames to be displayed and as soon as the image is done processing we want to process the next available frame.

Essentially having a faster framerate to display the webcam feed and slower detection rate to give the illusion of a fast frame rate.
I hope this explanation makes sense.

Here is my first attempt...:

---

```
private async Task CaptureCameraCallback(int selectedItemIndex, Image imageControl, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var idFaceDictionary = new Dictionary<long, object>();
            var classNames = await GetClassNames();
            var colorList = InitColorList(classNames.Count);

            using var capture = new VideoCapture(selectedItemIndex);
            using var frame = new Mat();

            while (true)
            {
                // Update the faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag based on the other flags
                faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag = !ObjectTracking && FaceRecognition;

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Set the image source to null
                    await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        imageControl.Source = null;
                    });
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                capture.Read(frame);

                if (!RunModel || !FaceRecognition & !ObjectTracking)
                {
                    await UpdateDisplay(frame.Clone(), imageControl);
                    continue;
                }

                if (ObjectTracking)
                {
                    // Process the image in a separate thread.
                    var processedFrame = await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var resultsList = await RunYolo(frame);

                        foreach (var results in resultsList)
                        {
                            if (!results.ContainsKey("class_")) continue;

                            var classIndex = int.Parse(results["class_"].ToString());
                            var className = classNames[classIndex];
                            var classColor = colorList[classIndex];

                            // Define the points for drawing rectangle
                            var topLeft = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["x"], (long)results["y"]);
                            var bottomRight = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["w"], (long)results["h"]);


                            string trackedName = null;
                            if (className == "person" && results.ContainsKey("track_id"))
                            {
                                var trackId = (long)results["track_id"];

                                if (FaceRecognition && !idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)) // Check if FaceRecognition is enabled
                                {
                                    var response = await RunRecognition(frame, results);
                                    if (response.ContainsKey("result") && response["result"] != null)
                                    {
                                        var resultStr = response["result"].ToString();
                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultStr))
                                        {
                                            idFaceDictionary[trackId] = resultStr;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (FaceRecognition) // Only add tracked name to the results when FaceRecognition is enabled
                                {
                                    trackedName = idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)
                                        ? $"{idFaceDictionary[trackId]} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                                        : null;
                                }
                            }
                            results["tracked_name"] = trackedName;

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackedName))
                            {
                                // Draw bounding box for object without tracked name
                                Cv2.Rectangle(frame, topLeft, bottomRight, classColor, 1);
                                var caption = results.ContainsKey("track_id")
                                    ? $"{classNames[classIndex].ToUpper()} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                                    : classNames[classIndex].ToUpper();
                                Cv2.PutText(frame, caption, topLeft, HersheyFonts.HersheyComplex, 1, classColor, 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Draw bounding box and name for tracked person
                                DrawPerson(
                                    frame,
                                    topLeft.X,
                                    topLeft.Y,
                                    bottomRight.X - topLeft.X,
                                    bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y,
                                    trackedName,
                                    classColor
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        return frame;
                    });
                    await UpdateDisplay(processedFrame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }
                if (faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag)
                {
                    var response = await faceRecognitionStandAlone(frame);
                    if (response["result"] != null)
                    {
                        string name = response["result"].ToString();
                        var coordinates = (Dictionary<string, int>)response["coordinates"];

                        int t = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["top"]);
                        int l = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["left"]);
                        int b = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["bottom"]);
                        int r = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["right"]);

                        var classColor = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);  // You can customize this color for your needs

                        DrawPerson(
                            frame,
                            l,
                            t,
                            r - l,
                            b - t,
                            name,
                            classColor
                        );
                    }
                    // We are assuming you want to update the image after processing
                    await UpdateDisplay(frame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }



            }
        }

        private async Task UpdateDisplay(Mat frame, Image imageControl)
        {
            await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                var bitmap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                var bitmapSource = ConvertToBitmap(bitmap);
                imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;
            });
        }
```

---

As you can see I tried to `Task.Run(async () =>` which made the capturing and display of the image faster but I know im doing something wrong(Please consider im a beginner with c# so take it easy on me).

- Here is my second attempt:

---

```
private async Task CaptureCameraCallback(int selectedItemIndex, Image imageControl, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var idFaceDictionary = new Dictionary<long, object>();
            var classNames = await GetClassNames();
            var colorList = InitColorList(classNames.Count);

            using var capture = new VideoCapture(selectedItemIndex);
            using var frame = new Mat();

            while (true)
            {
                // Update the faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag based on the other flags
                faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag = !ObjectTracking && FaceRecognition;

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // Set the image source to null
                    await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        imageControl.Source = null;
                    });
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                capture.Read(frame);

                if (!RunModel || (!FaceRecognition && !ObjectTracking))
                {
                    await UpdateDisplay(frame.Clone(), imageControl);
                    continue;
                }

                if (ObjectTracking)
                {
                    // Process the image synchronously
                    var processedFrame = ProcessFrame(frame.Clone(), classNames, colorList, idFaceDictionary);
                    await UpdateDisplay(processedFrame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }

                if (faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag)
                {
                    var response = await faceRecognitionStandAlone(frame);

                    if (response != null && response.ContainsKey("result") && response["result"] != null)
                    {
                        string name = response["result"].ToString();
                        var coordinates = (Dictionary<string, int>)response["coordinates"];

                        int t = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["top"]);
                        int l = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["left"]);
                        int b = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["bottom"]);
                        int r = Convert.ToInt32(coordinates["right"]);

                        var classColor = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);  // You can customize this color for your needs

                        DrawPerson(
                            frame,
                            l,
                            t,
                            r - l,
                            b - t,
                            name,
                            classColor
                        );
                    }
                    // We are assuming you want to update the image after processing
                    await UpdateDisplay(frame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }
            }
        }

        private Mat ProcessFrame(Mat frame, IDictionary<int, string> classNames, List<Scalar> colorList, Dictionary<long, object> idFaceDictionary)
        {
            var resultsList = RunYolo(frame).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            foreach (var results in resultsList)
            {
                if (!results.ContainsKey("class_")) continue;

                var classIndex = int.Parse(results["class_"].ToString());
                var className = classNames[classIndex];
                var classColor = colorList[classIndex];

                // Define the points for drawing rectangle
                var topLeft = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["x"], (long)results["y"]);
                var bottomRight = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["w"], (long)results["h"]);

                string trackedName = null;
                if (className == "person" && results.ContainsKey("track_id"))
                {
                    var trackId = (long)results["track_id"];

                    if (FaceRecognition && !idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)) // Check if FaceRecognition is enabled
                    {
                        var response = RunRecognition(frame, results).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        if (response.ContainsKey("result") && response["result"] != null)
                        {
                            var resultStr = response["result"].ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultStr))
                            {
                                idFaceDictionary[trackId] = resultStr;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (FaceRecognition) // Only add tracked name to the results when FaceRecognition is enabled
                    {
                        trackedName = idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)
                            ? $"{idFaceDictionary[trackId]} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                            : null;
                    }
                }
                results["tracked_name"] = trackedName;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackedName))
                {
                    // Draw bounding box for object without tracked name
                    Cv2.Rectangle(frame, topLeft, bottomRight, classColor, 1);
                    var caption = results.ContainsKey("track_id")
                        ? $"{classNames[classIndex].ToUpper()} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                        : classNames[classIndex].ToUpper();
                    Cv2.PutText(frame, caption, topLeft, HersheyFonts.HersheyComplex, 1, classColor, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Draw bounding box and name for tracked person
                    DrawPerson(
                        frame,
                        topLeft.X,
                        topLeft.Y,
                        bottomRight.X - topLeft.X,
                        bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y,
                        trackedName,
                        classColor
                    );
                }
            }

            return frame;
        }
```

--

- Here is my third attempt:

---

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Mat> frameQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Mat>();
        private ConcurrentQueue<Mat> processedQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Mat>();


        private async Task CaptureCameraCallback(int selectedItemIndex, Image imageControl, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var idFaceDictionary = new Dictionary<long, object>();
            var classNames = await GetClassNames();
            var colorList = InitColorList(classNames.Count);

            using var capture = new VideoCapture(selectedItemIndex);

            var frameQueue = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<Mat, int>>();
            var processedFrames = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Mat>();

            // capture task
            var captureTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var frameIndex = 0;
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    using var frame = new Mat();
                    capture.Read(frame);

                    if (frame.Empty())
                        continue;

                    if (!RunModel || (!FaceRecognition && !ObjectTracking))
                    {
                        processedFrames[frameIndex] = frame.Clone();
                        frameIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    frameQueue.Add(Tuple.Create(frame.Clone(), frameIndex));
                    frameIndex++;
                }

                frameQueue.CompleteAdding();
            });

            // process task
            var processTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var tuple in frameQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    var frame = tuple.Item1;
                    var frameIndex = tuple.Item2;

                    if (ObjectTracking)
                    {
                        var processedFrame = ProcessFrame(frame.Clone(), classNames, colorList, idFaceDictionary);
                        processedFrames[frameIndex] = processedFrame.Clone();
                    }

                    if (faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag)
                    {
                        var response = faceRecognitionStandAlone(frame).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                        // Continue your face recognition process...
                        processedFrames[frameIndex] = frame.Clone();
                    }
                }
            });

            // display task
            var displayTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var nextFrameIndex = 0;
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested || !processedFrames.IsEmpty)
                {
                    if (!processedFrames.TryRemove(nextFrameIndex, out var frame))
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100); // delay if no frames to display
                        continue;
                    }

                    await UpdateDisplay(frame, imageControl);
                    nextFrameIndex++;
                }
            });

            // await tasks to complete
            await Task.WhenAll(captureTask, processTask, displayTask);

            // Set the image source to null
            await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                imageControl.Source = null;
            });
        }


        private Mat ProcessFrame(Mat frame, IDictionary<int, string> classNames, List<Scalar> colorList, Dictionary<long, object> idFaceDictionary)
        {
            var resultsList = RunYolo(frame).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            foreach (var results in resultsList)
            {
                if (!results.ContainsKey("class_")) continue;

                var classIndex = int.Parse(results["class_"].ToString());
                var className = classNames[classIndex];
                var classColor = colorList[classIndex];

                // Define the points for drawing rectangle
                var topLeft = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["x"], (long)results["y"]);
                var bottomRight = new OpenCvSharp.Point((long)results["w"], (long)results["h"]);

                string trackedName = null;
                if (className == "person" && results.ContainsKey("track_id"))
                {
                    var trackId = (long)results["track_id"];

                    if (FaceRecognition && !idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)) // Check if FaceRecognition is enabled
                    {
                        var response = RunRecognition(frame, results).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        if (response.ContainsKey("result") && response["result"] != null)
                        {
                            var resultStr = response["result"].ToString();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultStr))
                            {
                                idFaceDictionary[trackId] = resultStr;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (FaceRecognition) // Only add tracked name to the results when FaceRecognition is enabled
                    {
                        trackedName = idFaceDictionary.ContainsKey(trackId)
                            ? $"{idFaceDictionary[trackId]} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                            : null;
                    }
                }
                results["tracked_name"] = trackedName;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackedName))
                {
                    // Draw bounding box for object without tracked name
                    Cv2.Rectangle(frame, topLeft, bottomRight, classColor, 1);
                    var caption = results.ContainsKey("track_id")
                        ? $"{classNames[classIndex].ToUpper()} - ID {results["track_id"]}"
                        : classNames[classIndex].ToUpper();
                    Cv2.PutText(frame, caption, topLeft, HersheyFonts.HersheyComplex, 1, classColor, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Draw bounding box and name for tracked person
                    DrawPerson(
                        frame,
                        topLeft.X,
                        topLeft.Y,
                        bottomRight.X - topLeft.X,
                        bottomRight.Y - topLeft.Y,
                        trackedName,
                        classColor
                    );
                }
            }

            return frame;
        }
```

---

Comment: Why do you feel you're doing something wrong? How do the current results differ from what you expect?

Comment: The only thing I could suggest changing (which is minor) is removing `async` from `UpdateDisplay` and change the `await` to `return` so you just return the `Task` from `InvokeAsync`. This isn't something you should *always* do, but see the article [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) to learn when to do that and when not to.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to create an illusion of a faster frame rate.  When your processing of a frame completes, are you going to display those results together with the frame used as input (causing your video to jump backwards)?  Or are you going to display those results together with the newest frame (causing the results to not match the image)?  Either one is probably going to be noticeable.  Not saying your plan is bad, just that you shouldn't expect "illusion".

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for your response! Yes so I would then want it to display the update bounding boxes on the latest frame. Yes this will  not create a full illusion but if my processing goes at 15 fps and my image is being displayed at 30 then it will be every two frames which is not bad, atleast the image being displayed will be at a smoother framerate. Would you have any advice?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thanks for your answer, the reason is because the image frame being displayed is still lagging abit, as it seems that it is still waiting for something to finish processing before being displayed. Instead if i dont run my model its allot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following methodology... it might not be the best but it seems to work greatly!

Here is the code:

```
private async Task CaptureCameraCallback(int selectedItemIndex, Image imageControl, CancellationToken token)
        {
            Mat latestFrame = null;
            BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, Scalar>> boundingBoxesInfo = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, Scalar>>();
            var currentBoundingBoxes = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<int, int, int, int, string, Scalar>>();

            var idFaceDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, object>();
            var classNames = await GetClassNames();
            var colorList = InitColorList(classNames.Count);

            using var capture = new VideoCapture(selectedItemIndex);
            using var frame = new Mat();

            Task processFrameTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Mat currentFrame;
                    if (latestFrame != null && RunModel && ObjectTracking)
                    {
                        currentFrame = latestFrame.Clone();
                        ProcessFrame(currentFrame, classNames, colorList, idFaceDictionary, boundingBoxesInfo);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                }
            }, token);

            while (true)
            {
                faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag = !ObjectTracking && FaceRecognition;

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        imageControl.Source = null;
                    });
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                capture.Read(frame);
                latestFrame = frame.Clone();

                if (!RunModel || (!FaceRecognition && !ObjectTracking))
                {
                    await UpdateDisplay(latestFrame, imageControl);
                    continue;
                }

                if (boundingBoxesInfo.Count > 0)
                {
                    while (currentBoundingBoxes.TryDequeue(out _)) { }

                    while (boundingBoxesInfo.TryTake(out var bboxInfo))
                    {
                        currentBoundingBoxes.Enqueue(bboxInfo);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var bboxInfo in currentBoundingBoxes)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bboxInfo.Item5) || bboxInfo.Item5 == "person") // Display if person is detected
                    {
                        DrawPerson(
                            latestFrame,
                            bboxInfo.Item1,
                            bboxInfo.Item2,
                            bboxInfo.Item3,
                            bboxInfo.Item4,
                            bboxInfo.Item5,
                            bboxInfo.Item6
                        );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Cv2.Rectangle(latestFrame, new OpenCvSharp.Point(bboxInfo.Item1, bboxInfo.Item2), new OpenCvSharp.Point(bboxInfo.Item1 + bboxInfo.Item3, bboxInfo.Item2 + bboxInfo.Item4), bboxInfo.Item6, 1);
                        var caption = bboxInfo.Item5.ToUpper();
                        Cv2.PutText(latestFrame, caption, new OpenCvSharp.Point(bboxInfo.Item1, bboxInfo.Item2), HersheyFonts.HersheyComplex, 1, bboxInfo.Item6, 1);
                    }
                }

                if (faceRecognitionStandAloneFlag)
                {
                    while (currentBoundingBoxes.TryDequeue(out _)) { } // Clear currentBoundingBoxes
                    await faceRecognitionStandAlone(latestFrame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }
                else if (ObjectTracking)
                {
                    await UpdateDisplay(latestFrame.Clone(), imageControl);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Absolutely! apologies for not giving a better explanation, i will update this answer within the day! thanks again for teh support.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous code is mostly meant to hide latency, most often IO latency. In your example the code will be run sequentially, just on different threads. So there will not really be any overall improvement.

What you want to do is to run thing *concurrently*, I would suggest a design that looks something like this:

1. One thread that reads from the camera
2. N threads that does the processing
3. One thread (the UI thread) that updates the UI

To make this easier I would suggest to start with refactoring your design to make the code look something like:

```
while(!token.IsCancellationRequested){
   capture.Read(frame);
   var result = DoProcessing(frame);
   UpdateUI(result);
}
```

This should help to separate the logic from the structure. And make further refactoring simpler.

There are a few potential problems with making this code run concurrently:

#### Managing buffers

You need to ensure a buffer is not concurrently read and written to. One solution is to simply copy the frames to newly allocated managed memory on the capture thread, and let the GC do the cleanup. A better solution is to use some type of pooling. Let the capture thread take buffers from the pool, and the UI thread return them once it is done. A very simple pool would be a [concurrentBag](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=c%23%20concurrentBag), try to take a buffer from the bag, if non are available, create a new one.

#### Ensure ordering

The UI thread should get frames in the correct order. This can be difficult if there are more than one processing threads.

For this I would suggest using  [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline). I.e. create a transform block that does the processing, and a action block that moves execution to the UI thread, i.e. `TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

Dataflow should ensure correct ordering, and uses internal buffers between each execution step. There is plenty of configuration possible for more advanced scenarios.

#### Other Notes

Any type of multi threaded code significantly raises the difficulty. It introduces many new potential sources for bugs, and many of them can be very hard to reproduce. So I would recommend spending a fair amount of time reading about thread safety and potential hazards before doing anything multi threaded.

You should start any optimization effort with doing a fair amount of measuring/profiling/benchmarking. This should help you identify where the performance problem is, and help you determine if your improvements actually help.

Comment: Hello! thanks soo much for your time and effort put into writing this answer. Based on what you said I tried to update my code accordingly and wrote down the code in my updated thread above. The issue now is that its running super slow because i think they are all running separately but awaiting to process each frame. I hope you can help

Comment: @NicolantonioDeBari Why do you use a *concurrentdictionary* to transfer frames between tasks? And why do you run a separate task just to post messages to the UI thread at all? You should just make your processing task call UpdateUI. And while blockingCollection can be useful for task parallelism, you will not be able to run processing concurrently, So I would still recommend dataflow.